# Proving that a function is Riemann non-integrable

Tags: riemann-sum

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function, and let $\mathcal{P}_{n}$ be a sequence of partitions (not necessarily evenly spaced) with mesh $m(\mathcal{P}_{n}) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Then $$|S_{L}(\mathcal{P}_{n})-S_{R}(\mathcal{P}_{n})|\to 0 \text{ for } n\to\infty$$

Note:

$$S_{L}(\mathcal{P}_{n}) = \sum^{n}_{k=1}f(c_{k-1})[x_{k}-x_{k-1}] \text{ and }S_{R}(\mathcal{P}_{n})=\sum^{n}_{k=1}f(c_{k})[x_{k}-x_{k-1}]$$ where $c_{k}$ is an internal point, ie. $c_{k}\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]$

Ok so I thought of the function $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } x\in\mathbb{Q}, \\ 0, & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}.\end{cases}$$

But I'm not sure how to progress with showing the difference between the Riemann sums doesn't converge to zero, i.e. showing the function is non-integrable.

How would I do this using **only** the information above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every partition, produce a finer partition an take all the $c_i$ to be rational, then take the same refinement partition and take all $c_i$ irrational.

One sum will be $0$ the other $1$.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this but surely we must use the same internal points for $S_{L}(\mathcal{P_{n}})$ and $S_{R}(\mathcal{P_{n}})$? If not can you explain why we can use different internal points for each one? To me it seems that taking different internal points results in two different regions being compared.

Comment: @user2850514 Nah! The definition (according to where you read) allows you to either use any points or to take the same points of the partition, or the maximum and/or minimum of each partition. Besides, when you change the partition you take new points. Notice I said refine the any partition given. So, we are not working with the given one, but a new one.

Comment: @user2850514 The definition says that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ so that **any finer partition** has Riemann sum $\epsilon$-close to the (to be) value of the integral. So, above, for any given a partition we build two finer ones that remain apart from each other.